# MongoDB deciding WinningPlan and RejectedPlans

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, compound-index

I have a mongo collection as below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6225a7b8d06fdc0abe145634"),
    "name" : "Max",
    "age" : 28,
    "salary" : 3000
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6225a7b8d06fdc0abe145635"),
    "name" : "Manu",
    "age" : 25,
    "salary" : 4000
}
```

I have three indexes for this collection:

1. The default **_id** index
2. Standalone **name_1** index
3. Compound index of **age_1_name_1**

When I executed a query like `db.customers.explain().find({name: "Max", age: 28})`, I was expecting the winningPlan to be the compound index, instead the winning plan was the standalone name_1 index and the rejectedPlan was the compound index.

Can anyone help me understand why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compound index need to be **name_1_age_1** to be possible to be used by the query ...

Comment: But then the Standalone index becomes redundant and doesn't let me use only the age key in the compound index for any future querying. @R2D2

Comment: You can drop the name_1 index if you create name_1_age_1 since the compound index will  cover both cases  and you can create age_1 to cover the option when you search only by age without using name ...

Comment: @R2D2 In my case, on passing the query params in the same order as the compound index one, still it is coming under rejected plans. I'm aware that `hint()` can be used here but how do I debug why the key is not getting picked when it is available and the query param's order is the same as the compound key one?

Comment: @y_159 : Generally I dont believe there is too much people with same name but different age , so the need of this index may need to be revised if necessary at all and selectivity to be analyzed , because there is a trade off here , compound index is bigger on size and more selective as it cover the two fields  , but single index on name  is smaller and maybe more effective  ...

Comment: @R2D2 I have a different dataset but the same scenario as described by op.

Comment: in my opinion if there is no too much values for age per name , only the name_1 index need to be used since the name maybe enougth selective , but afcourse for huge databases age part will be useful ...